# Proposition: $\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x + ...}}} = \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 4x}}{2}$.

Tags: radicals, nested-radicals

Proposition: $$\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x + ...}}} = \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 4x}}{2}$$

I believe that this is true, and, using Desmos Graphing Calculator, it seems to be true.

I will add how I derived the formula in a moment, if you would like.

**Working**

I will be honest; all that I did was use the Desmos Graphing Calculator, and let $y = \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x + ...}}},$ let $x = 1, 2, 3, ...$, looked at the point at which the two graphs meet, and searched for the number in Google.

It turned up an interesting website, which you may access [here](http://www.geteasysolution.com/), which seemed to show a pattern.

I used this pattern to derive the formula that I stated earlier.

Comment: I am sorry. I had to correct an error that I had made. The previous formula was the formula for $x + \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x + ...}}}$.

Comment: How do you define the infinite series of radicals? You have to make sure that this quantity is well-defined.

Comment: Maybe 12 minutes to accept an answer which does not solve the problem is slightly hurried?

Comment: @Did How does it not answer my question?

Comment: How does it answer it? Where do you see a proof, first, that the underlying sequence does converge (a point already made by @MihirSinghal) and, second, that it converges to this value? Physicists might be satisfied with the kind of post hoc verification that the posted answer suggests, but it would certainly make some eyebrows raise amongst mathematicians.

Comment: @Did I withdraw my prior comments. You are correct! :') I have unaccepted the answer, in the case that you may be able to provide a sufficient proof.

Comment: As I said, it happens that I can do that, but 1. this is irrelevant, 2. tons of other users can do that as well, and 3. I would be interested to know how YOU attack the problem, since at the moment you say nothing of the sort (in contradiction to the way questions ought to be asked on this site).

Comment: @Did Ah, you would like me to show some working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is true because :
$$S=\sqrt { x+\sqrt { x+\sqrt { x+... }  }  } \\ S=\sqrt { x+S } \\ { S }^{ 2 }-S-x=0\\ S=\frac { 1+\sqrt { 1+4x }  }{ 2 } $$

Comment: Ah, I see. I was not sure if it was a known result! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: you're welcome)

Comment: Sorry but this is not a proof. By the by, it seems that exactly the same approach could also "prove" that $S=\frac12(1-\sqrt{1+4x})$, no?

Comment: @Did I do not understand what you are talking about... Please, show me why this would ever be the case.

Comment: That's because the quadratic formula contains a $\pm$.

Comment: @MihirSinghal Ah, of course. I see, now! I am sorry.

Comment: @Taylor Sorry but the misconception in your previous comments seems to run even deeper... No, to be able to decree that a post does not prove something does not require that one can prove that a different result holds.  Actually I know that $S$ is not $\frac12(1-\sqrt{1+4x})$ and I know how to prove that it is not and I even know how to fulfill the program in two points that I described in my second comment to main, but all this is irrelevant to judge whether there is a proof in this answer. There is not.

Comment: @Did Okay, well, would you be able to provide me with a proof? I would happily accept it as an answer. :)

Comment: See comment to OP.

Answer (score 3):

First, I would like to mention that said series is not necessarily well-defined; you can't just add a "..." and expect the resulting quantity to be well-defined. For example, consider:
$$S=1+2+4+8+16+\ldots$$
Then,
$$2S=2+4+8+16+\ldots$$
so:
$$2S+1=S$$
and you get $S=-1$, which is clearly absurd. The issue here is that $S$ is not well defined; you have to define $S$ as the **limit** as $n \rightarrow +\infty$ of $1+2+\ldots+2^n$, and one can show that this quantity is $+\infty$. Similarly, you must instead ask for the limit of the sequence $a_n$, where $a_0=\sqrt{x}$ and $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{x+a_n}$. Now one can show that this sequence is increasing and is upper bounded, so it must converge (for $x>0$). Only once you have shown that it has converged can you use Nemo's approach (the comments about the quadratic formula's two solutions are easily resolved since the limit has to be positive).

Comment: Ah, okay. I see. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: this is not absurd in $2$-adics numbers

Comment: That is true, but my point is that you have to state a way to evaluate the infinite sum. Whether it be via a limit, 2-adic numbers, or other methods such as Césaro summation, you have to specify how to evaluate the sum.