# Why am I getting two answers for 8th root of continued fraction

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, quadratics, continued-fractions

Find value of $x$:

$x=\sqrt[8]{2207-\frac{1}{2207-\frac{1}{2207-....and\,so\, on}}}$

On solving ,we have $x^8=2207-\frac{1}{x^8}$

$x^8+\frac{1}{x^8}=2207$

$x^4+\frac{1}{x^4}=47$

$x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}=7$

$x+\frac{1}{x}=3$

$x=\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\,,\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$

But $x$ can take only one value.

The problem is which of these two values is to be accepted/rejected and why.

Comment: what justifys going from first to second equation, for example?

Comment: Could you explain the two equations below the second one? I'm not exactly sure how you arrived there.

Comment: You go from $x^8+\frac{1}{x^8}=2207$ to $x^4+\frac{1}{x^4}=47$. That is your problem. It is the start of your problems, in fact.

Comment: The equation with 47 looks OK to me, but I think in the next equation 9 should be 7.

Comment: Your infinite sum causes the problem here; see my answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1376667/proposition-sqrtx-sqrtx-sqrtx-frac1-sqrt1-4x2. In this case it is hard to make the infinite continued fraction well-defined, because it alternates values depending on the parity of the number of 2207's.

Comment: @Andreas Blass. you are right.I have edited.

Comment: @Cataline. Plase elaborate

Comment: The best way to solve the equation is to make the substitution $x^8=u$. Then it becomes a quadratic equation in $u$ (after you get rid of the $u$ in the denominator by multiplying out). Being honest, I'm not too sure what you are doing in your answer. Perhaps you could explain what you are doing then maybe we can see what's wrong?

Comment: @Cataline.Going according to what you say,$x^8=\frac{2207+987\sqrt{5}}{2}\,,\frac{2207-987\sqrt{5}}{2}$

Comment: $\sqrt{a+b}\ne\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$, in general.

Answer (score 3):

The 8th root is not pertinent.  You are asking how to assign a value to the continued fraction inside the 8th root.  As the equation for $x^8$ shows, there are two solutions of $f = 2207 - \frac{1}{f}$.

My first thought was that the even and odd "levels" of the continued fraction converge to the two different solutions (making it hard to distinguish the two solutions in principle) but I realized later that it is also possible that one of the solutions is attracting and the other repelling.  In this case the value of the attracting solution is the one that makes sense and the only one to which convergence will occur.

The graph of $y = 2207 - 1/x$ lies above the line $y=x$ between the two solutions.  This means the smaller solution is repelling and the larger one, attracting.  So the convergents of the continued fraction are pushed closer and closer to the larger value as long as one starts above the small solution. 
The fraction is thus $(\frac{3 + \sqrt{5}}{2})^8$.

Comment: $x^8=\frac{2207+987\sqrt{5}}{2}\,,\frac{2207-987\sqrt{5}}{2}$.Both are positive

Comment: That is why "the 8th root is not pertinent".  We are not looking for which value of the continued fraction is positive, so that the 8th root can exist.  The problem is to select one of the positive values, and then the 8th root is determined uniquely.

Comment: Yes. One way to think of the continued fraction is in terms of the sequence $x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2207-x_n}$. This sequence has two possible limit points (the two fixpoints) and the larger fixpoint is a repeller wheras the smaller one is an attractor. The only initial value $x_0$ that gives convergence to the larger fixpoint is if we start exactly at the larger fixpoint.

Comment: I thought the smaller is repelling and the larger one attracting.  $2207 - 1/x$ is increasing and above the diagonal $y=x$ between the fixed points.  For any x above the smaller fixed point, there is monotonic convergence toward the attractor.   @Winther

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I looked at a different map than you (with the same fixpoints). For the map $2207-\frac{1}{x}$ you are right the larger fixpoint is the attractor and likewise for the map $\frac{1}{2207-x}$ the smaller fixpoint is the attractor. Anyway, the idea to look at it in term of attracting/repelling fixpoints is the way to go here I think.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't notice that the function was different in your comment although it's standing right there.  @Winther

Answer (score 1):

You want the value which is greater than $1$ - clearly by estimating.

From $x^8+\frac 1{x^8}=2207$ you know that if $x$ satisfies that equation so will $\frac 1x$. Put $\frac 1x$ in the original equation and modify the eighth root accordingly and you will see where the alternative answer comes from and that this is clearly less than $1$.

Comment: Why should I prefer value greater than $1$

Comment: @PankajSinha Because you are calculating the eighth root of $2207$ less a little bit and the eight root of a number greater than $1$ is also greater than $1$ - in fact $2^8 = 256$ is clearly less than what you are looking for.

Comment: .Please correct me if I am wrong. According to you , the quantity under the $\sqrt[8]{...}$ sign is bigger than $2206$. Therefore, the value of x should be bigger than $\sqrt[8]{2206}$

Comment: @MarkBennet, there is a self-consistent possibility that 2207 is very close to the thing subtracted from it in the infinitely continued fraction.   Obviously that's true algebraically, the analysis question is more complicated (I think the business of attracting vs repelling fixed points).

Comment: @Mark Bennet,ASCII Advocate. I am inclined to agree with both of you. Can I say that $2206<x^8<2207$ and thus $\sqrt[8]{2206}<x<\sqrt[8]{2207}$. Therefore, the answer is $x=\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$,whereas the value of $\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is samller than $1$